# Phoenix API response time is slow? - NOPE

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an API-only Phoenix 1.3 system.  I'm noticing slow response times and seeing if anyone else has had this problem.

The scenario is fairly simple.  I have a database on a remote machine.  The roundtrip times for even the simplest query is about 140-156ms.   I am running the elixir/phoenix server on the local machine.

When I hit a simple endpoint from chrome, or curl or anything (again from the local machine),  the logs will report "Sent 200 in 141ms", with ecto reporting the db time as 140-141ms.  At first glance this is good news.  My expectation was that the db would take up most of the time, and encoding the response would be fast.  The log output from the server seems to show this.

However, on the chrome/curl side, the reported time ranges between 450-700ms -- nowhere near what the log is saying.  I would have expected the times to be much closer.

If the 200 time is in the 140ms range it tends to take 450ms to get to the client.  200 time moves north to 156ms, then the time reported at chrome/curl is closer to 700ms.

I've seen another question here similar where someone noted their priv/static was the issue -- however, even with that directory empty this still happens.

Some other random facts:

- Code reloading is set to false
- MIX_ENV dev and prod act exactly the same. Dev & Prod run on different ports, so I am sure I'm not just seeing dev.
- Using Encrypted session, but the endpoint I am using doesn't fetch or update the sesssion
- If I raise an exception at the beginning of the controller method, it will be received by chrome/curl in ~3ms
- The responses are small (< 600 bytes)
- Phoenix 1.3
- MySql -- mariaex 0.8.3
- Ecto 2.2.1
- Phoenix ecto 3.2.3
- timex 3.1.24
- elixir 1.5
- otp 20

Has anyone else seen this?  I'm sure I've overlooked something obvious. Any gotchas that could cause a huge delay from a reported "Sent" to a client on the local machine seeing the response?

Perhaps less obvious: Is it possible that the small responses aren't getting flushed somehow through the sockets until close because they are small?

**Update 3**:

Its looking like one of the big swings in response time are due to connections being slow to get into the endpoint.  New connections to the elixir/phoenix app seem to take 250-300ms before a request gets into the Phoenix.Endpoint.  If a request comes in over a reused connection its much faster (closer to what you would expect).  I'm not saying the actual tcp accept is slow -- just whatever happens between there and getting into App's EndPoint.

Any advice on where to look to see what may be causing this?  Is phoenix/ranch/cowboy doing something at initial connection that could bottleneck?  Or, is there a setting somewhere that I have overlooked?

**Update 4 / Solution to "Accept Latency"**

It looks like the I've solved the "accept latency" issue -- not an elixir problem at all as you probably guessed.  After much debugging of even the tools I was using to test, I found out that what I was using was trying to connect to localhost on ipv6 first, then ipv4.  The elixir process was only bound to ipv4. So it took about 250-300ms for a new connection from chrome, etc, to fail down from ipv6 to ipv4.

The solution for this was to add this to the config:

...

`http: [port: 4000, ip: {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}],`

....

Which makes the server wait for connections on ipv6 and ipv4. Made a world of difference.

Comment: Does the endpoint where you experience this use timex? It's a frequent source for performance issues unfortunately :/

Comment: No this particular route isn't using timex; and the inflated times are for every call no matter the resource.  Only one resource uses timex

Comment: It's difficult to troubleshoot such problems w/o direct access to the app, or more details regarding what's actually being done. Ecto does the same query plus marshalling etc. but the actual time spent depends on the query, the data model, etc. Once you've hit the wire all manner of interesting things can happen.

Comment: I know.  The problem is this is an internal proof of concept app to demonstrate the effectiveness of elixir/phoenix.  Its confidential, so I can't share it.  I understand this makes it hard,  I was hoping someone had run across similar issues.

Comment: The closest issue I've seen is slow TLS negotiation not being accounted for in the phoenix logger output, since it was occurring between the client and a load-balancer.